# How to use Azure Custom Commands API with react native (expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, azure, expo

I am trying to get Azure Speech Services Custom Commands to work with react native. I am unable to find examples in javascript that use Custom Commands. Has anyone created an application that I can refer to? I found the following resources but they do not show how to use Custom Commands specifically.

https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-sdk-react-native-example/tree/main/ExampleTSProject

This one has JS code but does not show how to use microphone to send audio to the API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-commands-setup-speech-sdk

This one has example in C# for which I wrote JS equivalent code which does not work.

This is my code right now, I am able to record audio using `expo-av` but don't know how to convert it to audio stream and pass it to SDK.

```js
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import { StyleSheet, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import * as SpeechSDK from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk';

const APPLICATION_ID = '6e3b5880-918e-11ed-a04e-cf28b0773cf7';
const SPEECH_KEY = '51ecddfd91564074b3cb2cee2f9e4f52';
const SPEECH_RESOURCE_REGION = 'centralindia'

export default function App() {

  const [recording, setRecording] = useState();
  const [dialogueServiceConnector, setDialogueServiceConnector] = useState();
  const [lastRecordedSound, setLastRecordedSound] = useState();

  function initializeDialogueServiceConnector() {
    const commandsConfig = new SpeechSDK.CustomCommandsConfig.fromSubscription(APPLICATION_ID, SPEECH_KEY, SPEECH_RESOURCE_REGION);
    const connector = new SpeechSDK.DialogServiceConnector(commandsConfig);
    connector.activityReceived = (sender, arg) => {
      console.log(`Activity received, activity=${arg.activity}`);
      let buff = [];
      arg.audioStream.read(buff);
      console.log(`Buffer: ${buff}`);
    }
    connector.canceled = (sender, arg) => {
      console.log(`Cancelled, reason=${arg.reason}`);
      if (arg.reason === SpeechSDK.CancellationReason.Error) {
        console.log(`Error: code=${arg.errorCode}, details=${arg.errorDetails}`);
      }
    }
    connector.recognizing = (sender, arg) => {
      console.log(`Recognizing! in-progress text=${arg.result.text}`);
    }
    connector.recognized = (sender, arg) => {
      console.log(`Final speech-to-text result: ${arg.result.text}`);
    }
    connector.sessionStarted = (sender, arg) => {
      console.log(`Now listening! session started, id=${arg.sessionId}`);
    }
    connector.sessionStopped = (sender, arg) => {
      console.log(`Listening complete. session ended, id=${arg.sessionId}`);
    }
    setDialogueServiceConnector(connector);
    console.log("initialized");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeDialogueServiceConnector();
  }, [])

  async function playSound() {
    if (lastRecordedSound) {
      await lastRecordedSound.playAsync()
    }
  }

  async function startRecording() {
    /*
    console.log(dialogueServiceConnector)
    dialogueServiceConnector.listenOnceAsync(() => {
      console.log("Recording complete")
    });
    setRecording(true);
    */
    try {
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });
      const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
        Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      setRecording(recording);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    /*
    setRecording(false);
    */
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: false,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
    });
    const { sound } = await recording.createNewLoadedSoundAsync();
    setLastRecordedSound(sound)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title={recording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
        onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
      />
      <Button
        title='Play recording'
        onPress={playSound}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```